# Message classification with Levenshtein Distance

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, edit-distance

I have a Python script that classifies messages. Each message carries a score, which is tallied up later in the script. It looks for messages that look alike, and puts them into a category.

```
items = []
cats = collections.OrderedDict()

# Do some preparation with the messages
punctuation_re = re.compile(r"([^\w\s.])")
multiple_spaces_re = re.compile(r"\s+")

# Load the messages from the CSV
with open('sentences.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=["message", "score"])
    for row in reader:
        match_desc = re.sub('(\s+)(a|an|and|the|is|are|or|to|on|under|in|about|at|have|had|was|were)(\s+)', '\1', match_desc)
        match_desc = re.sub(punctuation_re, "", match_desc)
        match_desc = re.sub(multiple_spaces_re, " ", match_desc)
        row["match_desc"] = match_desc.strip().lower()
        items.append(row)

# Match the items
for item in sorted(items, key=lambda x: len(x["match_desc"])):
    hasMatch = False

    if len(item["match_desc"]) <= 5:
        # Don't bother
        continue
    elif len(item["match_desc"]) > 15:
        # If the string is longer than 15 characters, use Levenshtein distance
        for k, v in reversed(cats.items()):
            # If string length difference is greater than maximum Levinshtein distance allowed, skip
            if (abs(len(item["match_desc"]) - len(k)) > math.ceil(len(item["match_desc"]) * 0.2)):
                continue

            # Else compute the Levenshtein distance
            if item["match_desc"] == k or Levenshtein.distance(item["match_desc"], k) < math.ceil(len(item["match_desc"]) * 0.2):
                cats[k].append(item)
                hasMatch = True
                break
    else:
        # Use exact match
        if item["match_desc"] in cats.keys():
            # Exact match
            cats[item["match_desc"]].append(item)
            continue
    if not hasMatch:
        cats[item["match_desc"]] = [item]
```

The problem is this script is \$O(n^2)\$, and struggles with large datasets as the script will need to go through more items to find a match. For example, a 70000-message dataset with varying lengths of messages takes 20 minutes on my machine (Python 3.6.3).

Some speedups I've included are:

1. Discarding messages that are too short
2. Only run Levenshtein distance if the string's lengths are similar (I use python-Levenshtein which is written in C)
3. Making `cats` an `OrderedDict()` and reversing it so that it's more likely to exit early (as the list of messages is sorted, it's more likely to find a match looking at what's recently inserted)

Are there any avenues of speedups possible that I'm missing?

Comment: if you **need** to compare *everything to everything else* it will be by definition O(n^2).

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I'm aware - I'm asking whether there are any early exit possibilities I'm missing in my code that could help speed up the script.

Comment: didn't exactly get how the grouping is done. Are the groups pre-defined or are they defined at runtime based on the messages?

Comment: Defined at run-time. If a message doesn't exist in `cats` already it is added; subsequent messages are grouped based on what exists in `cats`.

Comment: but then the order in which the messages is processed plays a role in the outcome. Different order results in a different group "definitions". Like semi-deterministic

Comment: Unfortunately yes - the source doesn't change however.